# Как задать значение ComboBox SelectedValue

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

Здравствуйте! Помогите пожалуйста. У меня есть ComboBox в форме

WPF код:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding GetController}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedController}"/>
```

c# код:

```
private Controller selectedController;
public IEnumerable<Controller> GetController
{
    get { return db.Controller.Local.Where(c => c.IsDelete != true); }          
}
public Controller SelectedController
{
    get { return selectedController; }
    set
    {
        if (selectedController != value)
        {
            selectedController = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedController));
        }
    }
}
```

Мне нужно выбрать Контролера по умолчанию, что бы когда вызвать Форму в `ComboBox` выбрано Контролер по умолчанию, я делаю это так:

```
private void ControllerView()
{
    ControllerForm cf = new ControllerForm();
    cf.DataContext = this;
    SelectedController.Id = 1;
    cf.ShowDialog();        
}
```

так не получается, выходит ошибка: Дополнительные сведения: Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.

Comment: А по какому критерию определяется контроллер, что это контроллер по-умолчанию? Это `SelectedController.Id = 1;` ?

Comment: Ура я нашел ответ

Answer (score 1):

Вот ответ:

```
private void ControllerView()
{
    ControllerForm cf = new ControllerForm();
    cf.DataContext = this;
    SelectedController = db.Controller.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == 1);
    cf.ShowDialog();        
}
```